# Let ymin be at most 0

Tags: pgfplots

I would like to make a graph of some points, where ymin is at most 0.
By default, `ymin` is the value of the lowest point in the graph. I would like to let `ymin` be the value of the lowest point or 0 if all points are positive.

Here is an illustration of what I want to obtain (in both cases where the lowest point is negative and not negative).
[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xtick={1,2,3}]
\addplot coordinates {(1,-1)(2,-3)(3,-4)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xtick={1,2,3},ymin=0]
\addplot coordinates {(1,5)(2,3)(3,2)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Remark : I am using currently the workaround consisting of adding a point at (1,0) with opacity=0. But I guess that there is a smarter solution.

Comment: `pgfplotstable` can be used to analyze data before plotting it, and set `ymin` accordingly.

Comment: I like your solution myself.

Comment: @Joseph Wright♦ Did I do the right thing [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/277597/give-a-threshold-value-to-automated-ymin-and-ymax/278705#278705)?

Comment: @Symbol1 Ah, I missed that one: should I dupe (or even merge)?

Comment: @JosephWright I do not know. The ultimate goal is to see it becoming an official feature. Then we can close both questions, haha.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's a style that checks whether the current `ymin` of the plots encountered so far is greater than the maximum allowed `ymin` (in your case that would be 0) and then sets the axis limit accordingly. The style also sets `enlarge y limits=upper` when `ymin` is constrained:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\makeatletter
\pgfplotsset{
    max ymin/.style={
        execute at begin axis={
            \def\pgfplots@usedmaxymin{0}
        },
        execute at end plot={
            \pgfmathfloatparsenumber{#1}
            \edef\pgfplots@maxymin{\pgfmathresult}
            \pgfmathfloatgreaterthan{\pgfplots@ymin}{\pgfplots@maxymin}
            \ifdim\pgfmathresult pt=1pt
                \xdef\pgfplots@ymin{\pgfplots@maxymin}
                \xdef\pgfplots@usedmaxymin{1}
            \fi
        }
    },
    before end axis/.code={
        \if1\pgfplots@usedmaxymin
            \pgfplotsset{enlarge y limits=upper}
        \fi 
    }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    max ymin=0
]
\addplot coordinates {(1,-1)(2,-3)(3,-4)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    max ymin=0
]
\addplot coordinates {(1,5)(2,3)(3,2)};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```