# Give a threshold value to automated ymin and ymax

Tags: pgfplots

In pgfplot, is it possible to give the automated scaling of your axis a minimal/maximal value? In other words; I want to have `y=0` always on the vertical axis in a way like:

```
ymin=min(0,minimum_plotted_value)
ymax=max(0,maximum_plotted_value)
```

This is my example code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
    x,value
    0, 3.2
    5, 6.5
    14, 6.8
    31, 2.2
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \centering
    \begin{axis}[
    ]
    \addplot table [x=x, y=value, col sep=comma] {data.csv};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Temporary approach

Add

```
\makeatletter
\gdef\pgfplots@ymin{0Y0.0e0]}
\gdef\pgfplots@ymax{0Y0.0e0]}
```

After `\begin{axis}`.

As one might guess: `\pgfplots@ymin` and its friends are the registers that PgfPlots uses to calculated the limits of the plot. The `min`'s are initialized to be 10<sup>2147483645</sup> and the `max`'s are initialized to be -10<sup>2147483645</sup>. Now, what you want PgfPlots to do is consider `0` as the first input and update the registers accordingly. Thus we need only to set them as `0` (which is `0Y0.0e0]` in FPU's notion) after they are initialized.

## Story

In `pgfplots.code.tex`:

In

```
\global\pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgfplots/xmin}{\pgfplots@xmin}%
\global\pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgfplots/xmax}{\pgfplots@xmax}%
\global\pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgfplots/ymin}{\pgfplots@ymin}%
\global\pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgfplots/ymax}{\pgfplots@ymax}%
\global\pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgfplots/zmin}{\pgfplots@zmin}%
\global\pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgfplots/zmax}{\pgfplots@zmax}%
```

PgfPlots reads the value of `xmin=` and its friends.

In

```
\pgfplotsutilforeachcommasep{x,y,z}\as\pgfplots@loc@TMPa{%
        \pgfplotscoordmath \pgfplots@loc@TMPa{min limit}%
        \expandafter\let\csname pgfplots@invalidrange@\pgfplots@loc@TMPa max\endcsname=\pgfmathresult
        \pgfplotscoordmath \pgfplots@loc@TMPa{max limit}%
        \expandafter\let\csname pgfplots@invalidrange@\pgfplots@loc@TMPa min\endcsname=\pgfmathresult
    }%
```

PgfPlots set `pgfplots@invalidrange@xmin` to be 10<sup>2147483645</sup> and so on.

In

```
\ifx\pgfplots@xmin\pgfutil@empty
    \pgfplots@autocompute@xmintrue
    \global\let\pgfplots@xmin=\pgfplots@invalidrange@xmin
\else
    \pgfplots@autocompute@all@limitsfalse
\fi
```

PgfPlots check if `\pgfplots@xmin` is empty. That is, it checks if you assign any value to `xmin`. If so, then it turns off the limit-computation for min of x-axis. If not, then `\pgfplots@xmin` is 10<sup>2147483645</sup> and PgfPlots is ready to compute the limit.

## Conclusion

If you ever assign a `xmin=` then PgfPlots will turn off the limit-computation. But we can turn it on manually:

```
\makeatletter
\pgfplotsset{
    ymin*/.code={
        \pgfkeysalso{ymin=#1}
        \pgfplots@autocompute@ymintrue
    },
    ymax*/.code={
        \pgfkeysalso{ymax=#1}
        \pgfplots@autocompute@ymaxtrue
    }
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[ymin*=0,ymax*=0]
            \addplot table[x=x, y=value,col sep=comma] {data.csv};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

You can even set `ymin*=-1,ymax*=1` so that the axis will always contain that interval.